# H2 console doesn't Create Table with Entity Class

Tags: java, spring, database, jpa, entity

Yo, cant resolve this simply problem in h2-console..
I want just create table via Entity class like "MOvie" or "director" but when i open my h2-console,is not created, pls help

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>sk.wynny</groupId>
    <artifactId>springLearn</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springLearn</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**app-properties**

```
spring.h2.console.enabled= true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:wynny
spring.datasource.username=root
```

**MOVIE CLASS**

```
package sk.wynny.modul;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Movie() {
    }

    public Movie(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**LOGs**

```
2022-02-13 20:11:37.031  INFO 5856 --- [           main] s.w.springLearn.SpringLearnApplication   : Starting SpringLearnApplication using Java 17.0.1 on DESKTOP-K3O8I67 with PID 5856 (C:\Users\Patrik Severín\IdeaProjects\springLearn\target\classes started by Wynny in C:\Users\Patrik Severín\IdeaProjects\springLearn)
2022-02-13 20:11:37.034  INFO 5856 --- [           main] s.w.springLearn.SpringLearnApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-02-13 20:11:37.638  INFO 5856 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-02-13 20:11:37.653  INFO 5856 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 5 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-02-13 20:11:38.249  INFO 5856 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-02-13 20:11:38.260  INFO 5856 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-02-13 20:11:38.260  INFO 5856 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
2022-02-13 20:11:38.362  INFO 5856 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-02-13 20:11:38.363  INFO 5856 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1281 ms
2022-02-13 20:11:38.398  INFO 5856 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-02-13 20:11:38.553  INFO 5856 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-02-13 20:11:38.563  INFO 5856 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:wynny'
2022-02-13 20:11:38.735  INFO 5856 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-02-13 20:11:38.789  INFO 5856 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.4.Final
2022-02-13 20:11:38.949  INFO 5856 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-02-13 20:11:39.073  INFO 5856 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2022-02-13 20:11:39.263  INFO 5856 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-02-13 20:11:39.273  INFO 5856 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-02-13 20:11:39.321  WARN 5856 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-02-13 20:11:39.602  WARN 5856 --- [           main] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2022-02-13 20:11:39.734  INFO 5856 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-02-13 20:11:39.746  INFO 5856 --- [           main] s.w.springLearn.SpringLearnApplication   : Started SpringLearnApplication in 3.068 seconds (JVM running for 3.417)
```

i following many videos or manuals and still have same problem, is here some Hero what can resolve it  ? :D

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in Thymeleaf engine, if i create spring only  with h2,web and jpa is working nicely.Idk why problem is with Thymeleaf..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).